# Show multiple buttons in Data grid view

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I needed to add two buttons inside a single column in data grid view in Visual Foxpro, , but only one active appears in the column.
the two buttons could be shown in each cell of that column.
Is it possible to show both buttons?

Answer (score 2):

> I needed to add two buttons inside a single column in data grid [...] Is it possible to show both buttons?

Yes, you can put a `Container` object into the `Grid.Column` and put two Buttons into the `Container`. Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
LOCAL oForm as Form
oForm = CREATEOBJECT('TestForm')
oForm.Show(1)
RETURN

DEFINE CLASS TestForm as Form
    AutoCenter = .T.
    PROCEDURE Load
        LOCAL i
        CREATE CURSOR temp (test Int)
        FOR i = 1 TO 10
            INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i)
        ENDFOR
        GO TOP
    ENDPROC

    ADD OBJECT Grid1 as Grid WITH ;
        RecordSource = 'temp', ColumnCount = 1, RowHeight = 30
    PROCEDURE Grid1.Init()
        WITH This.Column1
            .Width = 200
            .AddObject('Container1','TestContainer')
            .Container1.Visible = .T.
            .CurrentControl = 'Container1'
            .Sparse = .F.
        ENDWITH
    ENDPROC
ENDDEFINE

DEFINE CLASS TestContainer as Container
    Width = 200
    Height = 27
    ADD OBJECT Button1 as CommandButton WITH ;
        Height = 24, Caption = "Button1"
    PROCEDURE Button1.Click
        MESSAGEBOX(This.Caption)
    ENDPROC
    ADD OBJECT Button2 as CommandButton WITH ;
        Height = 24, Left = 100, Caption = "Button2"
    PROCEDURE Button2.Click
        MESSAGEBOX(This.Caption)
    ENDPROC
ENDDEFINE
```